# I encountered a very strange question about LLDB modifying variables

Tags: swift, xcode, lldb

I set the breakpoint at line 29, and I want to modify the value through LLDB to let him enter the == 1 situation, but I found that this breakpoint jumped to line 33 without hitting it, which is very strange.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let v = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 300))
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        view.addSubview(v)
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let value = test()
        print(value)
    }

    func test() -> Bool {
        let m = 3
   29     if m == 1 {
            print(m)
            return true
        } else {
   33        print(m)
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

[Where the breakpoint hit 29 but But the breakpoint jumped to line 33 without hitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzA6Q.png)

When I set the value of m to a random number, the breakpoint can stay at line 29, and the value can be modified to make him enter a different state, which makes me very confused

```swift
   func test() -> Bool {
        let m = arc4random()
        if m == 1 {
            print(m)
            return true
        } else {
            print(m)
            return false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is strange that you did not notice the following warning

[image]

knowing that the compiler just thrown that part of code from built executable away and debug info, for those lines so is absent, as a result debugger just jump through it to existed part of code.

Comment: I can understand that as long as this warning pops up, the bottom layer of the program will not compile and generate that code, and directly enter the else, right?

Comment: @Zuqiu, I would say there is no `else` at all, just `let m = 3; print(m); return m;`

Comment: There is also a very strange thing, I have `20` lines on your picture, execute the LLDB command `e m = 10`, and then execute the `po m` result is 10, but after executing 20 lines, the result is `printed as 3`, it seems that LLDB has not changed this Value, if you don't reproduce it, you can change  `let` to `var`。Do you know why this is